# asp.net razor doesn't recognize C# models even it is working

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have the models in another project, I put models references in the **_ViewImports.cshtml** file under the area, everything working fine, but in the razor view, all C# classes not recognized, like this:
[image]

When I put the references inside the view, all recognized. The strange thing is sometime all views recognize the models, sometime not!.

I don't have any extensions, and I tried building the solution, emptying caches.